# Kmeans with Spark

Tags: python, mapreduce, k-means, apache-spark

The following is a part of Kmeans algorithm which is written with Apache Spark:

```
closest = data.map(lambda p: (closestPoint(p, kPoints), (p, 1)))
pointStats = closest.reduceByKey(lambda (x1, y1), (x2, y2): (x1 + x2, y1 + y2))
newPoints = pointStats.map(lambda (x, (y, z)): (x, y / z)).collect()
```

Can anyone explain to me how does it work? Assuming we have two clusters and 1000 points and we want to run it in cluster with two slave nodes and one master node. I think the first function (closest) can be considered as mapper and the second one would be combiner but what about the last  function what it is suppose to do? and which one act as reducer?

Comment: It is written in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the `reduceByKey` a function that can be used as a combiner and reducer, because you are required to pass it an aggregate function, if your use case can't use a combiner you need to use `groupByKey`. And yes anytime you call `map` on an RDD in spark the function you pass it can be viewed as a mapper. You should definitely take a look at the [`RDD` docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) and the [`PairRDDFunctions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions). Keep in mind a spark program will tend to have multiple stages of mapping and reducing since it attempts to keep intermediate output in memory, where as standard Hadoop MapReduce reads from and writes to disk every time. Also if you are using spark you can use the [k-means in MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html)

UPDATE:
In reference to your comment the reason they "map the (overall sum / num points) to every slave node" is because the way spark works means this has no overhead. Since spark uses a DAG for every RDD nothing is calculated until an action (like `collect()` in this case) is performed) so the map at the end can actually seamlessly get the output of the reducer, which shouldn't spill to disk since it is very small. This is similar to a [`ChainReducer`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainReducer.html) in Hadoop however in spark every step in connected RDDs is kept in memory (obviously this is not always possible, so sometimes it will spill to disk, this also depends on the serialization level). So basically the last calculation will in reality be done on the same node as the reducer (no shuffle needed after) and only then collected to the driver.

Comment: Thank you for the response-- I still cannot understand the last method,actually it is just a simple function which is a division for a overall sum into the number of points, assuming we have two clusters so it is just two simple calculations. My question is why the author used a map func which maps (overall sum / the number of points) to every slave node?

Comment: @user3789843 checkout the update I think it clarifies your confusion

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand the spark code, the first thing to do is understand k-means.  As a high level overview, k-means does these steps:

1. randomly chose k points as the centroids of your clusters
2. decide which of your data points belong to the clusters defined by your k centroid points
3. choose new centroids based on the average of the points in a cluster
4. repeat steps 2 & 3 until you decide your are finished

your first line is step (2) of the algorithm; your second and third lines are step (3) of the algorithm.  What those two lines are doing are finding the average of all of the points in a cluster.

The final 'collect' method call moves the data from an RDD to the local machine (in preparation of broadcasting the new centroids back out the all of the nodes in your Spark environment). In order to repeat steps (2) and (3), you have to distribute the knowledge of what the current centroids are out to each node.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking how k-means works, but great explanation, now I actually understand it +1

Comment: my hidden point is that it is better not to think of the problem via the lens of map/combine/reduce, but rather to think first of how the problem works, second how does data get distributed across the cluster, and then what operations need to be done to the data locally in each partition, and globally in the driver program.

Comment: Judging from the OP's response to my answer I think they were just confused about the differences between, standard Hadoop MapReduce and how an RDD gets calculated across the cluster