# Decrease number of tasks in a Spark stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, task, amazon-emr, stage

I am running a spark sql job in aws EMR which reads ~100k small JSON files from s3, does a few transformations, and writes results back to s3. I have set shuffle partitions and default parallelism to 20 and executor memory to 4GB. However, for one of the stages **javaToPython at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java**, as shown in UI which I understand writes to s3, has nearly 2.7k tasks with input data size < 1MB. Same behavior for the stage with a **collect** action. I don't understand why? What am I missing here?
I have also tested the app by reducing the number of partitions (with coalesce) in the application but nothing seems to change. I am running pyspark 2.4.7 and EMR-5.33.1

Comment: Could you share your code and all configs from spark UI?

Answer (score 0):

I think to understand what you're observing you'll need to understand your cluster details and configurations.

Some assumptions in your application:

- You didn't implement threading in your application

The number of tasks are defined by parallelism (total concurrent tasks)- which is defined by the

- Number of executors
- Number of cores for each executor
- Number of partitions

Please take a read of [how stages are split into tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528047/how-are-stages-split-into-tasks-in-spark)

With that - another thought is that you mentioned

> ~100k small JSON files

If you haven't already, make sure to review and understand the [Small Files Problem](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/spark-sql-small-file-problem.html)

The section called

> 3. Hazards of small files

States

> 2. It is easy to cause too many tasks. If it exceeds the configuration of the parameter spark.driver.maxResultSize (default 1g), the
>    following exceptions will be thrown, affecting the processing of tasks
>    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
>    failure: Total size of serialized results of 478 tasks (2026.0 MB) is
>    bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB) Of course, you can
>    increase the default configuration of spark.driver.maxResultSize to
>    solve the problem, but if you can't solve the small file problem from
>    the source, you may encounter similar problems in the future.
>
> In addition, when Spark processes tasks, one partition is assigned a
> task for processing, and multiple partitions are processed in
> parallel. Although parallel processing can improve processing
> efficiency, it does not mean that the more tasks, the better. If the
> amount of data is small, too many tasks will affect the efficiency.

Understanding how tasks are created (configuration wise and application wise) + what your Spark application is trying to ingest, will help you understand what your application is doing.