# When does shuffling occur in Apache Spark?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

I am optimizing parameters in Spark, and would like to know exactly how Spark is shuffling data.

Precisely, I have a simple word count program, and would like to know how spark.shuffle.file.buffer.kb is affecting the run time. Right now, I only see slowdown when I make this parameter very high (I am guessing this prevents every task's buffer from fitting in memory simultaneously).

Could someone explain how Spark is performing reductions? For example, the data is read and partitioned in an RDD, and when an "action" function is called, Spark sends out tasks to the worker nodes. If the action is a reduction, how does Spark handle this, and how are shuffle files / buffers  related to this process?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Question : As for your question concerning **when shuffling is triggered on Spark?***

*Answer :* Any `join`, `cogroup`, or `ByKey` operation involves holding objects in hashmaps or in-memory buffers to group or sort. `join`, `cogroup`, and `groupByKey` use these data structures in the tasks for the stages that are on the fetching side of the shuffles they trigger. `reduceByKey` and `aggregateByKey` use data structures in the tasks for the stages on both sides of the shuffles they trigger.

*Explanation : **How does shuffle operation work in Spark?***

The shuffle operation is implemented differently in Spark compared to Hadoop. I don't know if you are familiar with how it works with Hadoop but let's focus on Spark for now.

On the **map side**, each map task in Spark writes out a shuffle file (os disk buffer) for every reducer – which corresponds to a logical block in Spark. These files are not intermediary in the sense that Spark does not merge them into larger partitioned ones. Since scheduling overhead in Spark is lesser, the number of mappers (`M`) and reducers(`R`) is far higher than in Hadoop. Thus, shipping `M*R` files to the respective reducers could result in significant overheads.

Similar to Hadoop, Spark also provide a parameter `spark.shuffle.compress` to specify compression libraries to compress map outputs. In this case, it could be `Snappy` (by default) or `LZF`. `Snappy` uses only 33KB of buffer for each opened file and significantly reduces risk of encountering out-of-memory errors.

On the **reduce side**, Spark requires all shuffled data to fit into memory of the corresponding reducer task, on the contrary of Hadoop that had an option to spill this over to disk. This would of course happen only in cases where the reducer task demands all shuffled data for a `GroupByKey` or a `ReduceByKey` operation, for instance. Spark throws an out-of-memory exception in this case, which has proved quite a challenge for developers so far.

Also with Spark there is no overlapping copy phase, unlike Hadoop that has an overlapping copy phase where mappers push data to the reducers even before map is complete. This means that the shuffle is a *pull* operation in Spark, compared to a *push* operation in Hadoop. Each reducer should also maintain a network buffer to fetch map outputs. Size of this buffer is specified through the parameter `spark.reducer.maxMbInFlight` (by default, it is 48MB).

For more information about **shuffling** in Apache Spark, I suggest the following readings :

- [Optimizing Shuffle Performance in Spark](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs262a-F13/projects/reports/project16_report.pdf) by Aaron Davidson and Andrew Or.
- [SPARK-751](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-751) JIRA issue and [Consolidating Shuffle files](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12637642/Consolidating%20Shuffle%20Files%20in%20Spark.pdf) by Jason Dai.

Comment: I have a follow up question: How does spark choose which tasks will serve as which reducers? In other words, how does spark decide where to "pull" the shuffle files for reducing?

Comment: The answer for the one is quite long. I suggest that you read the answer for a this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836316/where-to-learn-how-dag-works-under-the-covers-in-rdd)

Comment: @eliasah Does Spark requires all shuffled data to fit into memory of the corresponding reducer task still? ReduceByKey operation in my spark program throws an out-of-memory exception in this case. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes concerning that so I'll say "yes, that property is still valid". As for your second question, it is a little broad to answer in a comment, I suggest you ask a new question on that concern with more details. (What do you think @zero323 ?)

Comment: Sorry, I am `Spark` fresher and not quite understandable with **shipping** word in the sentence of   **Thus, shipping `M*R` files to the respective reducers could result in significant overheads.** It should be like the `copy` or `move` operation or anything else? I have tried to search it before but didn't get a suitable description.

Comment: @BowenPeng what I meant about shipping it's indeed copy/move like behaviour. Does this answer you question ?

Answer (score 2):

It occurs whenever data needs to moved between executors (worker nodes)