# What is the principle of DagScheduler in Spark?

Tags: algorithm, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

[here is the Scala code in github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala)

It is hard to read the code to understand the mechanism of DAG. Wish someone could explain the mechanism of DAG.
I know it schedules the job and tasks of Spark.But I don't know the detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to learn how DAG works under the covers in RDD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836316/where-to-learn-how-dag-works-under-the-covers-in-rdd)