# Debugging a filter operation in scala through `in-code variable inspection`

Tags: scala, apache-spark, debugging, filter

I am new to scala and wish to debug this piece of code to see why I do not get any results.

```
>  def main(args:Array[String]){
>     Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
>     val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","WordCountRe")
>     val input = sc.textFile("data/book.txt")
>     //With regexp
>     val words = input.flatMap(x=>x.split("\\W+"))
>     //Lower case
>     val lowerCaseWords = words.map(x => x.toLowerCase())
>     val wordCounts = lowerCaseWords.map(x => (x,1)).reduceByKey((x,y)=>x+y)
>     val sortedWordCounts = wordCounts.sortBy(-_._2)
>     val commonEnglishStopWords = List("you","to","your","the","a","of","and","that","it","in","is","for","on","are","if","s","i","with","t","this","or","but","they","will","what","at","my","re","do","not","about","more","an","up","need","them","from","how","there","out","new","work","so","just","don","","get","their","by","some","ll","self","make","may","even","when","one","than","also","much","job","who","was","these","find","into","only")
>     val filteredWordCounts = sortedWordCounts.filter{
>       x =>
>         val inspectVariable = commonEnglishStopWords.contains(x._1)} //Error here
>     filteredWordCounts.collect().foreach(println)   } }
```

When I try to use this code, I get a compile error :

> type mismatch;  found   : Unit
>   required:
>   Boolean   WordCountRe.scala   /SparkScalaCourse/src/com/sundogsoftware/spark  line
>   29    Scala Problem

This thread [How to find data inside a rdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006030/where-to-find-data-inside-a-rdd-in-a-eclipse-spark-scala-debug-session) seems to have the solution I tried to apply, except I must be using it wrong.

Thank you for your help

EDIT : Found what was wrong with my code (needed to put a `._1` in the contains in order to parse the word in the tuple (word, count)), but I still don't know how to debug/inspect values in such a situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you assigned boolean result of method `contains` to a val `inspectVariable`. This operation has a return type of Unit. But `filter` method requires boolean.

Just remove `val inspectVariable =` and this should fix it.

Or return the value by adding new line with content `inspectVariable` after assigning the value.

As shown here

```
val filteredWordCounts = sortedWordCounts.filter { x =>
  val inspectVariable = commonEnglishStopWords.contains(x._1)//put your breakpoint here
  inspectVariable
}
```