# Rules for DAG optimization in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Does Spark optimizes the DAG on encountering an action? I am aware that DAGScheduler pipelines transformations into a single stage. What I am trying to find is if there are any other optimization that are being applied on the DAG. And if so, in what situations are they applied(maybe you can point me to the rules or the code where it is explained).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836316/how-dag-works-under-the-covers-in-rdd

Comment: @thebluephantom I had already gone through that answer but it does not answer my question of optimization